# Is metric number theory an active research field?

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, soft-question, research

It seems that there are not so many papers in metric number theory as there are in other branches of number theory. I know that researchers in ergodic theory are sometimes interested in metric number theory and usually Diophantine approximation, but i was wondering if it is an active research field on its own, are there a lot of researchers that focus on it?

Comment: I'd say most papers in number theory use many different tools and concepts coming from many different fields.

Comment: What do you count as metric number theory? Just as an example, did you see the bibliography for [geometry of numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers)?